# SuperCollider FreqScope axis values do not correspond to frequencies

Tags: frequency-analysis, supercollider

I have a problem with FreqScope in SuperCollider. The signal frequency does not correspond to the frequency axis. If I start a Sinus-Ugen with
`{SinOsc.ar (1000)}.play;`
I get the following picture
[image]

I use SuperCollider 3.11.2 on a Debian Linux 11.5 BullsEye OS.
Any idea, why this happens and perhaps how to solve this?

Comment: That's really weird. Can you post all of the code you used to get that picture? What sample rate are you running at? (Evaluate ```s.sampleRate```)